# Drag and drop .app files into NSImageView and get the file path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I have an NSWindow containing and NSImageView. I want that the user can drag 'n drop a .app file (application) into the NSImageView, and my application see which file is dropped. Is there a way to do this (okay, I'm sure there is a way to do this -_- but which one :p )?

So much like iWeb does it with image files.

A tutorial would be nice (english or dutch).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Subclass NSImageView
2. Implement [NSDraggingDestination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingDestination_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
   protocol
3. Register an instance of your
   subclass to accept your defined
   PBoardType

Here is a well written tutorial (it's a bit old, but maybe useful):
http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000056.php